# Does a GINA implementaion allow me to ignore SAS kernel calls?

Tags: windows, windows-7, gina

I am aware that this had been asked MANY times, but i've spent a good amount of time looking at all of them I could find, and I haven't gotten a good answer. I do understand the concept of an NMI and I am aware that I cannot intercept the call. I was just wondering if I were to develop a GINA application, could I respond to ALL the hooks that the operating system calls so that I can just ignore them? Are there some hooks that get executed regardless of my GINA implementation? I have run across many little utilities that will tweak the registry for me, but I want to handle it all in code without changing the registry.

PS, I **DO NOT** want to write my own keyboard driver nor do I want to hack around in BIOS land...

Also, I have read that Win 7 does not use GINA. Am I wrong? If not, what Windows component do I need to implement/replace in order to do the same thing?

Comment: You are correct that Win7 does not use GINAs.

Comment: Removed 'SAS' tag - that refers to the 4GL statistical programming language, not your intended usage of SAS (an overloaded acronym if I've ever seen one).

Comment: I think SAS is *Secure Attention Sequence*

Comment: Yes, in this case it is - but the "SAS" tag on Stackoverflow is not.

Comment: I've used custom GINAs.  For the record, they do allow you to ignore the SAS, but it will still have some side-effects; for example, it will clear the effect of the BlockInput function.  All irrelevant, unfortunately, since you're developing for Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried RegisterRawInputDevices with the RIDEV_NOLEGACY flag?  (My guess is that this won't work, but I don't know whether anyone has ever tried.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GINA was killed by Vista. So you are right that it's not present in Windows 7. The replacement functionality is credential providers. They certainly don't allow you to intercept SAS.

Comment: Blast, is there anything I can do in win7 to respond to SAS hooks exclusively?

Comment: No. If there was it wound render the SAS as insecure.